# Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv

Tags: video, downloads, youtube, youtube-dl

I was trying to download from the YouTube

```
youtube-dl -F 249 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXT1ElMEkW8"
```

My version `youtube-dl --version` is 2019.11.28

I went through the link [Requested formats are incompatible for merge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806258/requested-formats-are-incompatible-for-merge), but could not help to resolve the issue

> [youtube] yXT1ElMEkW8: Downloading webpage
>   [youtube] yXT1ElMEkW8: Downloading video info webpage
>   WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv.
>   ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '1.6 - Cloning Repo and Push_Pull - Git and GitHub for Poets-yXT1ElMEkW8.f247.webm.part'

Answer (score 1):

```
youttube-dl -f 249 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXT1ElMEkW8
```

Option -F  List all available formats of requested videos

with the option -f you can choose the format, you want.